# border not going in input box in html

Tags: html, css, input, textarea, border

i have a form with some input fields in html, i have designed it with css. I have put the form inside bootstrap modal, i have done the following css to make the input box without borders:

```css
input {
 outline: none;
 border: none;
}

textarea {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }

input::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
input:-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
input::-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
input:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}

textarea::-webkit-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
textarea:-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
textarea::-moz-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder { color: #adadad;}
```

the borders are not displayed when the form is loaded but as soon as we click the input box to enter data some transparent border is appearing like below:

[image]

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add your html to the snippet also?

Comment: try to add `input:focus{border:none;outline:none}`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky added that also, still that border is coming